# MariaDB is not working

Tags: mariadb

I have installed mariadb using below commands:

```
yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client -y
```

But when execute commane:

```
service mysqld start
```

Error is coming:

```
mysqld: unrecognized service
```

Please let us know what wrong I am doing or what additionally I have to do to make it work.

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: Kolt Penny I didn't get u? Doing it on Centos6.5

Comment: are you sure `MySQL` is installed?

Comment: Distro means? Sry I am new so might I didn't understand what you are referring to as Distro

Comment: Have you tried using sudo or are you running on root?

Comment: I am trying it as root

Comment: Alihossein Shahabi I have run service mysqld status, its also saying same mysqld: unrecognized service

Comment: How to check whether mariadb has been installed or not?
 rpm -qa |grep Mysql its not showing any output

Comment: Any clue what wrong or what I am missing?

Comment: Where is the online documentation for installing MariaDB on CentOS 6.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly verify that service sees MySQL using command:
`sudo service --status-all`

If you see MySQL there run command:
`sudo service mysql start`